# what is the latest version of cython compatible with kivy master?

Tags: python, kivy

what is the latest version of cython compatible with kivy master? I'm having trouble compiling using kivy==master and cython==0.29.21. When installing the latest cython=3.11, the compiler works, but the application closes when starting on Android. My code is simple, just a hello world that works normally on Android and is compiled normally when I leave "requiriments = python3,kivy" and cython==0.29.21

Comment: would this help? https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.11.1/installation/deps-cython.html